# Multiple rows in a page and updating just one row, Performance Issue?

Tags: sql-server, file, io

As we know pages are basic IO units in SqlServer.

Assume that there are more than one row that are stored in a page. So the rows must be reletively short.

But what will happen when just one of them is being updated? Will the entire page be re-written? Is it logical to re-write all the 8k bytes again when only a few bytes are necessary to be re-writte?

Comment: The entire dirty page will be eventually written to disc as a unit. Before than happens the changes will be written to the transaction log. What is written there depends. It can just be the offset in the row and the diff.

Answer (score 1):

The entire 8K page will be updated since that is the lowest level of SQL Server IO.  Remember that it is not just the row data itself that is modified, but potentially page and row header structures of the page too (plus PFS pages, etc.).

Whether SQL Server physically writes one byte or the entire 8K page doesn't matter from a performance perspective.  The writes are performed asynchronously after the in-memory-only update of the 8K page.  Most of the I/O cost is in the IOP itself.

Comment: @DanGuzmen: Thanks. But why do you claim writing just one byte is not different from writing 8K? It is obvious 8K case needs more time.

Comment: Against traditional spinning media, most of the time spent in IO is seek time.  The seek time latency, typically measured in milliseconds,is the same regardless of the amount of data transferred.  The data transfer itself is microseconds.